# Kill all child processes of a parent but leave the parent alive

Tags: c, unix, process

What would be the best way to kill all the processes of a parent but not the parent? Let's say I have an undetermined number of child processes that I've forked and on a given alarm, in my signal handler, I'd like to kill all my child processes but keep myself running for various reasons.

As of now, I am using kill(-1*parentPid, SIGKILL) but this kills my parent along with its children.

Comment: can you simply keep track of the children's PIDs in a simple array as you fork them?

Comment: I tried that but since the amount of processes to be forked is not known, I'd have to keep a counter of how many have been made in order to index them correctly and the counter variable's state is not well defined across multiple processes...of course, my implementation of that could be poor.

Comment: So you can sent a signal to both parent and children ,right ?

Comment: Lidong, that's part of the quandry, in my current implementation only the parent registers the signal handler...heck, I might as well post the code.

Comment: is that you https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13654257_1241676249176088_6752481851487002381_n.jpg?oh=084f85b5b7e517c94ffad10790875a3d&oe=582467FF :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to deliver some signal that can be caught (not `SIGKILL`). Then, install a signal handler that detects if the current process is the parent process or not, and calls `_exit()` if it is not the parent process.

You could use `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`, or perhaps `SIGQUIT`.

I've illustrated this technique [here](https://tio.run/##nVRdb9MwFH3vr7gEbXK1DlJQeVjaSUgU1BckaCeQxlS5idtY9Zzij5WB@tvLtZM2ialUCT8lx9fnnnvvsdPrVZru9y@5TIXNGAy1yXjxKr/ttCDBFyGmuFwFGF9JKtoYU0oGdFRrpozDoIFayTFPQJjmzENN7Fm/3lJend/wbG5gQxWTZo4/SSfNqYJHvbp/M3j3kGDIU8EzQGk/LTfznMpMMAWES@PALvzpAK5SE0EERiOYTj59uZvMuonfK3NoJpYwghUz@E@qLb4EUieHFyMfdiB1a6u4YaTfc5J6gF0TTBL87lYMbs3ZL25IXCG7zg5VO32PlEsg3U7J5hDeVJTmXGQu7/3AF@p2yhGQqoBeWPeholpyq6Jy0xpNIkGtxARyVabB@Kg6vFwKq3OCwyqsOWCFaymSxQlwGMIggasr3uxDNSgMwdg1aVSvt9ykOfaxGZ5SzSC@Of77QLlBz5klKVvJf7PCf3d7EF1k4JqIen/IqOfH2z0U1sjllZQkka8LlJUST93ARXb25KnKj@IEYxvyNg5guijQVg3QF3bdb1e2wVtSKBK51kTnGDK2pFaYNkPtBf6APd60ORaK0XUN7SqfNeft9btx99HCaSGzg46ysH5gjzUX4pQ5HE7iXnCDztvDX0dDjdW1TH8qSZphgfmR0T0F5LI8GnTOXc4y7BZiuLyEb5OP4@@T2fgDqeI96KDp7P3sbnqE8QmIw7T/Wgc9p22aMm2FeAZ3zWoH@YhAzw6YwOHXsoalLP9EupzjyefZ11N5cR5obctO8p2QWdnJ9Sa000lL1ab4H8cMKsfotmUGgWWyQrJDhGLGKol26Oz2@78).

Optionally (as suggested by Lidong), the parent process can use `SIG_IGN` on the signal before issuing the `kill()` command.

```
signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
kill(0, SIGQUIT);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set the child process a new process group at the fork time, and while you want to kill the child process and its descendants, you can use **killpg**, example code as:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void parent(pid_t pid) {
    killpg(pid, SIGKILL);
}

void child(void) {
    if (-1 == setsid())
        return;

    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("child\n");
    } 
}


int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    switch ((pid=fork())) {
    case 0: // child
        child();
        break;

    default: // parent
        getchar();
        getchar();
        parent(pid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't higher. This works great and is a very clean way to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Jxh 's answer is nice. Howevr , maybe you can just give a `signal hander` for every children process after `fork` and let it call `exit` function . and you give a `signal hander` for parent and let it `ignore` the signal (like `SIGUSR1`). this may add the code lines but you don't need detect the process is parent or child in signal hander function.

Comment: Hi Lidong, a small example would go a long way to illustrating what one should do =)