# Why won't Go kill a child process correctly?

Tags: go, exec

The following works just fine when cmd finishes in the allotted time.  However, the timeout is not working.  While it does print `"It's dead Jim"`, not only does it fail to print `"Done waiting"`, but the process is not actually killed.  It continues to run, and `"Done waiting"` never prints.

```
func() {
    var output bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command("Command", args...)
    cmd.Dir = filepath.Dir(srcFile)
    cmd.Stdout, cmd.Stderr = &output, &output
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer time.AfterFunc(time.Second*2, func() {
        fmt.Printf("Nobody got time fo that\n")
        if err := cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGKILL); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error:%s\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("It's dead Jim\n")
    }).Stop()
    err := cmd.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Done waiting\n")
}()
```

I don't think it should make a difference, but for what it's worth the command is `go test html`.  The reason it's timing out is because I'm injecting an error that causes an infinite loop before running it.  To add to the confusion, I tried running it with `go test net`.  There was a timeout, and it worked correctly.

Comment: One reason might be is that `Kill()` only sends the process the `TERM` signal which the process is free to ignore or process specially. The signal might also not be delivered if the target process is blocked (say, it's currently in a non-restartable syscall). To be sure, make `Kill()` send the `KILL` signal.

Comment: @kostix, thanks for pointing that out.  The [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Process.Kill) is rather ambiguous.  I'm now sending SIGKILL explicitly, and it's still not working.

Comment: Since `SIGKILL` should kill the process for sure (unless it's somehow *seriously* wedged) I'm inclined to think there's some other problem. In your real code, do you check the call to `os.Process.Kill()` for error?

Comment: As of Go 1.7 the preferred way to provide cancellation or timeout for a child is by using [`exec.CommandContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext) and arranging to cancel or timeout the context.

Comment: Kill() sends SIGKILL, which can't be caught or ignored. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597543/golang-kill-an-os-process-with-exec-exiterror#44597759). Calling cancel on a context also sends SIGKILL.

Answer (score 24):

Looks like the problem is that cmd.Process.Kill() doesn't kill child processes. See this similar question [Process.Kill() on child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982845/process-kill-on-child-processes)

I found a solution in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/XoQ3RhFBJl8

```
cmd := exec.Command( some_command )
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
cmd.Start()

pgid, err := syscall.Getpgid(cmd.Process.Pid)
if err == nil {
    syscall.Kill(-pgid, 15)  // note the minus sign
}

cmd.Wait()
```

As a caveat this will almost certainly not work across platforms - I'm on OSX Yosemite at the moment, and I'd be willing to bet it'd work on most Linuxes as well, but I don't know enough about BSD to have an opinion and I doubt it would work on Windows.

Comment: some reference (C): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433585/kill-all-child-processes-of-a-parent-but-leave-the-parent-alive

Comment: I'm on Yosemite and unfortunately it doesn't seem to kill all the child processes. I'm executing the GAE sdk but it fails to kill all its children (i.e. the http port remains open so I guess some subprocesses are still running)

Comment: For me, ONLY the child processes were killed, using this solution. But replacing the `syscall.Getpgid()` and `syscall.Kill()` lines with a simple `cmd.Process.Kill()` _did_ kill the parent and all its child processes. FYI. (I still used `Setpgid: true` though.)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure when it was added, but as of Go 1.11 you can set the `Pdeathsig` on a subprocess to `syscall.SIGKILL`. This will kill the child when the parent exits.

```
cmd, _ := exec.Command("long-running command")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGKILL,
}
cmd.Start()

os.Exit(1)
```

The `cmd` should be killed on exit.

Answer (score 12):

Just for reference, I'll put my Windows solution here as well:

```
func kill(cmd *exec.Cmd) error {
    kill := exec.Command("TASKKILL", "/T", "/F", "/PID", strconv.Itoa(cmd.Process.Pid))
    kill.Stderr = os.Stderr
    kill.Stdout = os.Stdout
    return kill.Run()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your calling process can create a new session on posix systems with setsid.  When you execute the following your code becomes the process group leader if (it isn't already that is). When you kill the process group leader the children die too.  At least, that is my experience.

```
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setsid: true}
cmd.Start()
time.Sleep(5)
if err := syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL); err != nil {
        log.Println("failed to kill: ", err)
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Not sure why this had 0 votes, but this worked for me and is slightly simpler than the setpgid solution.

Answer (score -3):

Go's defer statement schedules a function call (the deferred function) to be run immediately before the function executing the defer returns.

So the things after defer

```
defer time.AfterFunc(time.Second*2, func() {
    fmt.Printf("Nobody got time fo that\n")
    cmd.Process.Kill()
    fmt.Printf("It's dead Jim\n")
}).Stop()
```

wouldn't be executed unless func() ends. Therefore, if "cmd.Wait()" never end, the "time.AfterFunc()" is never executed.

Removing "time.AfterFunc(...)" from defer can fix this problem, since "time.AfterFunc" could waits for the duration to elapse and then calls f **in its own goroutine**.

Here is a working version. I tested in my ubuntu box and it works.
Save source as wait.go

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "time"
import "bytes"
import "fmt"


func main() {
    var output bytes.Buffer
        cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "10s")
        cmd.Stdout, cmd.Stderr = &output, &output
        if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("command start error\n")
                return
        }
        time.AfterFunc(time.Second*2, func() {
                fmt.Printf("Nobody got time for that\n")
                cmd.Process.Kill()
                fmt.Printf("It's dead Jim\n")
        })
        cmd.Wait()
        fmt.Printf("Done waiting\n")
}
```

Run the command:

```
time go run wait.go
```

Output:

```
Nobody got time for that
It's dead Jim
Done waiting

real    0m2.481s
user    0m0.252s
sys 0m0.452s
```

As @James Henstridge has commented that the above understanding is incorrect. Actually I had incomplete understanding of defer. The other half is "The arguments to the deferred function (which include the receiver if the function is a method) are evaluated when the defer executes". So the timer is truly created when defer is executed and thus timer will time out.

The problem is really why the process cannot be killed. I checked the go's pkg's code, it sends a SIGKILL in *nix like system to kill the process. The SIGKILL cannot be blocked and ignored. So it could be other possibilites such as the process itself is in [TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE](http://lwn.net/Articles/288056/) state.

Comment: Are you sure about that? What is being deferred is the `Stop` call on the `*Timer` returned by `time.AfterFunc`.  E.g. http://play.golang.org/p/p1vuHNQWxK

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. I had incomplete understanding of defer. "The arguments to the deferred function (which include the receiver if the function is a method) are evaluated when the defer executes". So the timer is truly created when defer is executed and thus timer will time out. @kostix pointed out the potential reason of why kill doesn't work.

Comment: @jeffruan I don't think it's possible that the process could be in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state because its memory footprint continues to grow.

Comment: @Floegipoky, did you try ps or top to check its state? D is uninterruptible state. Or did you try to kill the process manually by running a shell kill command when go code's kill execution failed. This is just to know whether there is difference.

Comment: @jeffruan, the process state is `R`.  Running `kill <pid>` does successfully kill the process.

Comment: @Floegipoky, sounds odd. if `kill <pid>` can do, so probably it could suspect the signal by go code actually wasn't delivered for some reasons. Maybe it's worth of trying another way of using `exec.Command("kill", <pid>)`. If it had worked, it would tell there are probably problems inside `cmd.Process.Signal`. Besides, Fields SigPnd & ShdPnd of `proc/<PID>/status` can provide some information on the pending signals of the process. Usually they should be all zeros. That can be checked when the process are not killed.