# Process.Kill() on child processes

Tags: go

I'm trying to stop the process started with `exec.Command("go", "run", "server.go")` and all its child processes.

But when I call `cmd.Process.Kill()` and the `go` process stops, the child process (a web server in `server.go`) continues to run.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func run() *exec.Cmd {
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "run", "server.go")

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return cmd
}

func main() {
    cmd := run()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)

    err := cmd.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cmd.Process.Wait()

    // === Web server is still running! ===

    fmt.Scanln()
}
```

It looks like `Process.Kill()` only stops the `go (run)` process, but leaves its child process (web server) running.

`^C` kills the whole process group, including all child (and sub-child) processes. How can I do the same?

I tried `cmd.Process.Signal(os.Interrupt)`, `syscall.SIGINT`, `syscall.SIGQUIT` and `syscall.SIGKILL`, none of which did anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the `go run` command. Use `the go install` command to install your packages and programs and then execute your program.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why `go run` doesn't work? Is it a problem that will occur with other commands (outside of `go`) as well?

Comment: Approximately, `go run` internally does a `go build -o prog` and `./prog`, so when you kill the `go run` process, you don't kill it's subprocess `./prog`.