# How to start and monitor and kill process with Go

Tags: go

I am writing a program in Go that should open a portable browser to a given page and monitor it, so that if the browser is closed, it should be automatically reopened. Also the browser should be closed when the program exits.

So far I have managed to reopen the browser when the user closes it, however I am not being able to close it.

Here is my code:

```
package browser

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"

    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

type iBrowserHandler interface {
    Start(processListener chan bool) error
    Stop() error
    KillProcess() error
}

type browserHandler struct {
    cmd            *exec.Cmd
    pathToChromium string
    pdvEndpoint    string
}

func newBrowserHandler(pathToChromium string, pdvEndpoint string) iBrowserHandler {
    b := &browserHandler{}
    b.pathToChromium = pathToChromium
    b.pdvEndpoint = pdvEndpoint

    return b
}

func (b *browserHandler) Start(processListener chan bool) error {
    endpoint := fmt.Sprintf("--app=%s", b.pdvEndpoint)

    b.cmd = exec.Command(b.pathToChromium, endpoint, "--kiosk")
    err := b.cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Error("Error with the browser process")
        processListener <- false
    } else {
        processListener <- true
    }

    return err
}

func (b *browserHandler) Stop() error {
    err := b.cmd.Process.Release()
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("Error shutting down chromium")
    }

    return err
}

func (b *browserHandler) KillProcess() error {
    err := b.cmd.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("Error killing chromium process")
    }

    return err
}
```

And this is the function that I am using to start the browser:

var handler iBrowserHandler

```
func init() {
    var pathToChromium string
    var c = config.GetInstance()
    var os = runtime.GOOS

    if os == "windows" {
        pathToChromium = "chromium-browser\\ChromiumPortable.exe"
    } else {
        pathToChromium = "chrome"
    }

    handler = newBrowserHandler(pathToChromium, c.GetConfig().PDVUrl)
}

func StartBrowser(done chan bool) {
    browserProcessListener := make(chan bool)
    defer close(browserProcessListener)
    go handler.Start(browserProcessListener)

    var tryReopenBrowser = true
    for {
        select {
        case <-browserProcessListener:
            if tryReopenBrowser {
                log.Warn("Browser process is stopped. Attempting to restart")
                go handler.Start(browserProcessListener)
            } else {
                log.Warn("Browser process is stopped. Will not attempt to restart")
            }

        case <-done:
            log.Info("Shutting down browser")
            tryReopenBrowser = false
            handler.KillProcess()
            return

        default:
        }
    }
}
```

When the program starts I call the StartBrowser() function. Once the browser is started, it keeps listening to see if it was closed (the `cmd.Run()` function blocks the execution of the thread until the process finishes).

If the browser was closed, then my program attempts to reopen it.

If the program receives a stop signal, it tries to close the browser. I tried to use both the `cmd.Process.Release()` and the `cmd.Process.Kill()` commands, but both do not close the browser. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Do `Release`/`Kill` return errors? Or just do nothing? (Also totally unrelated but the whole `iBrowserHandler interface` is bad form for Go, looks like you may be used to C#?)

Comment: No, they don't return any errors, they just don't do anything.

Comment: And yes, I am used to C# and other OO languages and I am new to Go... :) How should I name the interface and the struct so I can differentiate them?

Comment: It's not just naming... read up on proper use of interfaces in Go. You shouldn't create them at all unless you actually need them (which it doesn't appear you do, especially since these are unexported); they should be named based on their behavior, not just "IClassName" after the class that implements it; and they should be defined where they're consumed, not where they're implemented.

Comment: You also don't need the empty `default:` case in your `select`, it actually turns it into a tight loop and causes unnecessary CPU load. If you leave it with just the two "real" cases, it will wait (efficiently) until one of the channels receives a message.

Comment: Ok, I will change those things. I created the interface on the first place to that I could mock my struct when I write some unit tests. I just haven't had the time to create them yet. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Note: I also tried to run my code with the Firefox portable browser and the result was the same. I could not close it with `Kill` or `Release`.

Comment: @Felipe: it will break your monitoring logic, but see if if `Kill()` works if you start the process with `Start()` rather than `Run()` to see if the implicit `Wait` call is blocking something. (`Release()` is not what you want to use)

Comment: Also, these browsers are probably starting multiple subprocesses, maybe killing the parent doesn't terminate the children. Have you looked at the running processes before and after? Have you tried sending a signal other than Kill which probably prevents any cleanup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer! The problem is that the Go `cmd.Process.Kill()` command only stops the parent process, but not the child processes, so I had to kill these processes manually through the OS.

Since I am on Windows my `KillProcess()` method now looks like this:

```
func (b *browserHandler) KillProcess() error {
    log.Info("Killing browser process")
    kill := exec.Command("taskkill", "/T", "/F", "/PID", strconv.Itoa(b.cmd.Process.Pid))
    err := kill.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Error("Error killing chromium process")
    }
    log.Info("Browser process was killed")

    return err
}
```

**Credits:** this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470193/why-wont-go-kill-a-child-process-correctly) has an answer for both [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551450/839211) and [Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552044/839211) systems.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `cmd.Run()` use `cmd.Start()` [see this](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Start)

Comment: Hi, I changed my code to run `Start()` instead of `Run()`, but it is still not working... The `Release` method doesn't do anything and the `Kill` method only stops the main process.

Comment: I've been looking at the task manager and @JimB is right, Chrome and Firefox spawn other processes that aren't killed when I execute the `Kill` and `Release` methods. Maybe there is a way to kill the process tree (to kill child and parent processes), but I haven't found it yet.