# Go does not kill GUI based processes even after setting the process group pid

Tags: go, unix

So I wanted to launch a process and kill it using my Go code. Here is the code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("subl")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // wait for the process to complete
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    pgid, err := syscall.Getpgid(cmd.Process.Pid)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(cmd, " can't kill ", err)
    }
    syscall.Kill(-pgid, 15)
}
```

I set the group process id after reading this answer hoping that it would work [Why won't Go kill a child process correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470193/why-wont-go-kill-a-child-process-correctly)

But if I open processes like firefox, or sublime it launches them, but can't kill them saying   `no such process` but I can still see the browser or the editor window open after my program exits. How do I properly kill such processes? processes that finish even if they are running.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go, and relatively little to do with Unix either: when you launch certain GUI commands, they poke around a bit and see that there's already an existing one running. Instead of opening a *new* GUI, they send a message to the existing one, telling it: "hey, you existing GUI, go do this for me" ... and then they *quit*. There is nothing to kill, because the command you ran already quit.

Comment: Your code actually depends on this property: you *wait for the subprocess to quit* before you go on, using `cmd.Wait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code waits for the processs to complete and then tries to kill it. There is no process to kill surely?
I expect that what is happening is that the browser or other app is spawning a new process from iteself and then exiting the original process, which is when your code returns. The browser is still running but the proces that spawned it is already dead.

This is common with applications that keep only 1 main process running - such as if you launch 3 browser processes they will signal to the first one to open new tabs.

Comment: so is there no way to completly kill such processes?

Comment: @shinigaami25: If you successfully kill the browser, *all* the user's windows go away, not just the one you opened. Don't do that!