# Firebase emulator does not stop when run with Golang exec command

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-tools

I'm using the information in this [article](https://www.captaincodeman.com/2020/03/04/unit-testing-with-firestore-emulator-and-go) to build tests for Firestore using the firebase emulator.

The emulator starts correctly, tests run, but the despite the SIGKILL (and I tried other signals) the emulator is not cleaned up after the tests finish.

This is how my `main_test.go` looks like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    // command to start firestore emulator
    cmd := exec.Command("firebase", "emulators:start")

    // this makes it killable
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

    // we need to capture it's output to know when it's started
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stdout.Close()

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var result int
    defer func() {
        syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
        os.Exit(result)
    }()

    started := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        buf := make([]byte, 512, 512)
        for {
            n, err := stdout.Read(buf[:])
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break
                }
                log.Fatalf("reading stdout %v", err)
            }

            if n > 0 {
                d := string(buf[:n])

                // only required if we want to see the emulator output
                fmt.Printf("%s", d)

                // checking for the message that it's started
                if strings.Contains(d, "All emulators ready") {
                    started <- true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        done <- cmd.Wait()
    }()

    select {
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        log.Fatal("Failed to start the command for 10 seconds")
    case err := <-done:
        log.Fatalf("------\nCommand has finished unexpectedly with error: %v", err)
    case <-started:
        fmt.Println("--------")
        log.Print("Command started successully... running tests")
    }

    log.Print("BEFORE running tests")
    result = m.Run()
    time.Sleep(time.Minute) // to simulate that it take some times to run tests
    log.Print("AFTER running tests")
}
```

The output of `go test . -v` is looking ok:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4000 │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────--------
2020/10/13 16:20:29 Command started successully... running tests
2020/10/13 16:20:29 BEFORE running tests
testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
2020/10/13 16:20:29 AFTER running tests
ok      go/src/test (cached) [no tests to run]
```

But firebase emulator is not properly cleaned up (if I start the same command again, it fails complaining that port 4000 is already in use). The following processes are found lingering:

```
### snippet from netstat -anp:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25187/firebase
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      25160/cloud-firesto

### snippet from ps axu:
user 25187 /usr/local/bin/firebase /home/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.1.1/server.bundle.js
...
user 25160 /home/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.7.jar --launcher_javabase=/usr/local/buildtools/java/jdk11 -Duser.language=en run --host localhost --port 8080 --rules /home/firestore.rules
```

Any ideas what's wrong?
... or other ideas on how to test my main function (that uses Firestore as a backend)?

Comment: Could the negative sign before the pid in `syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)` be an issue?

Comment: No, that is not the issue. I tried without negative, I tried different signals, I tried several signals one after another.  There are always lingering processes.

Comment: I see, negative pid is valid, to kill processes in a group. Try changing `Setpgid` to `Setsid` in the line &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}` to create a new session & process group.

Comment: Tried your suggestion of changing `Setpgid` to `Setsid`... but no luck.

Comment: The `syscall.Kill(...)` function can return an error, try catching that and log it if non nil.

Comment: The emulator is starting child processes with different group and session ids. Suggest changing `syscall.SIGKILL` to `syscall.SIGINT`. This should send an interrupt (Ctrl C) to the firebase process, asking it to cleanly shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Go `exec` does not kill the child processes. More details here:  [Why won't Go kill a child process correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470193/why-wont-go-kill-a-child-process-correctly)

Per the recommendations in [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2716) I decided to use:

```
firebase emulators:exec "go test"
```

which clears the emulator correctly after the tests finish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but changing from `SIGKILL` to `SIGINT` solved it for me. That is, I changed:

```golang
    defer func() {
        syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
        os.Exit(result)
    }()
```

to

```golang
    defer func() {
        syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGINT)
        os.Exit(result)
    }()
```

I was glad this worked, because using the `firebase emulators:exec "go test"` method didn't let me keep my existing CI setup.